# Cut off half of the SVG's text element

Tags: svg

How can I make this

[image]

to look like this

[image]

So I want to halve the text element. I don't want to hide half of the text outside of **SVG**. Hiding it outside of **g** would be ok, but haven't found solution.

```
<svg width="500" height="500">
 <g transform="translate(50,50)">
    <rect width="80" height="50" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);"/>
    <text font-size="40" x="0" y="15" fill="black">SVG</text>
 </g>
</svg>
```

**JSFIDDLE:**
http://jsfiddle.net/64nkLcdy/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath) property :

```html
<svg width="500" height="500">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="myClip">
      <rect width="80" height="50" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <g transform="translate(50,50)">
    <rect width="80" height="50" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);" />
    <text font-size="40" x="0" y="15" fill="black" clip-path="url(#myClip)">SVG</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an `<svg>` element rather than a `<g>` as the svg element will clip its contents by default. The overflow property controls clipping i.e overflow="visible" doesn't clip but overflow="hidden" does.

```html
<svg width="500" height="500">
 <svg transform="translate(50,50)" width="80" height="50" overflow="hidden">
    <rect width="80" height="50" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);"/>
    <text font-size="40" x="0" y="15" fill="black">SVG</text>
 </svg>
</svg>
```